# Open link in new internal windows django, python

Tags: python, django

I need create web site with some links to another resources and I would like when visitor click in one of this links the new windows is opened in the same page, and then visitor can close this window and open another link ... in python and django its possible?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that using HTML inline frame. Basically you will embed another HTML page in yours by creating a new browsing context for the embedded page.

[Mozilla Docs - HTML iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe)